# Area between a parabola and a line

Tags: calculus, integration, conic-sections, area

[image]

Hello, can someone explain me, or at least give me some instructions, in order to understand why is the surface of the arc given by that integral?

I've done some research and nothing that i do is reaching such simplicity. I've already tried partial derivation, diferential equations...

Comment: See here: https://www.analyzemath.com/calculus/Integrals/area_between_curves.html

Comment: I edited title and tags to give a better idea of the matter. The area you must find is comprised between a parabola and a line, a standard exercise in integration.